# Eclipse changing line numbers

Tags: eclipse

I am debugging my code, I first noticed it skipping over my breakpoints which I assumed was due to something with spring. However I've also noticed that it has changed the line numbers as flows:

[image]

I've not faintest idea why Eclipse would be randomly doing this.

Comment: Why do you have comments as line numbers? and skipping breakpoints, are you debugging or running it?

Comment: Debugging it, Eclipse added these random comments.

Comment: Random comments don't get added on their own.  Are you using some special plug-in or launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to me as decompiled Java code.

The line numbering is not generated by Eclipse, but by a third party decompiler (if that's the case).

Side note:

Check your debug configuration to disable the decompiler as it should not be running at all if you are only debugging!

Comment: Correct you are I was referencing an older version of my own maven module. A tricky one to watch for.